# SwiftUI Is this using trailing closure syntax when creating an instance of struct that conforms to View Protocol?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having some problem understanding how this can be allowed in Swift..

Original way of creating a VStack view would look like this:(option1)

```
 VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20, content: {Text("d")})
```

But normally we do like this:(option2)

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                    Text("d")
                }
```

So at here `VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20, content: {Text("d")})` this is a instance of struct VStack, and when creating an instance of it, the third parameter takes closure as a parameter.(`() -> _`).

1. But here is that even the closure is being taken as a parameter, we can use trailing closure syntax, and use code like option2?
2. and I also see many people saying "views are a function of their state". But how this can be possible? aren't we returning instance of Struct that conforms to View Protocol using opaque return type in the computed property called body like below:

   struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
   Text("d")
   }
   }

Comment: It is the same, just syntax sugar - read swift book at developer.apple.com.